# Как запретить выделение в браузере?

Tags: javascript

Браузер выделяет текст при перемещении объектов с помощью DnD. Как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно отменить действие по умолчанию во время перетаскивания.

```
function cancel(e) {
    // Non-IE
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // IE 
    else {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще можно применить к элементу следующие свойства стиля:

> ```
> user-select: none;
> -moz-user-select: none;
> -khtml-user-select: none;
> -webkit-user-select: none;
> ```